# Macro for removing the `restrict` keyword when compiling with C++

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

I need to include some headers originally written in **C** in a C++ project. In the header files, the [`restrict` keyword](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restrict) is used, which leads to a syntax error for C++.

I am looking for a preprocessor macro which checks whether I am compiling with a C++ compiler and removes the `restrict` keyword in this case.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#define restrict
#endif
```

should do it. `restrict` is not a keyword in C++, so `#define`ing it to nothing is unproblematic there.

Or, as [Arne Mertz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1838266/arne-mertz) suggested, better still, have

```
extern "C" {
#define restrict
// include C headers here
#undef restrict
}
```

where you include the C headers in your C++ source.

Comment: defining `restrict` to nothing would be legal even in C (since the preprocessor transforms the source before the C compiler sees it), but it wouldn't be what's intended.

Comment: if you put the `#define` in the C++ code before including the C headers (together with the `extern "C" {` you are going to need), you won't even need the `#ifdef/#endif`. Try to be minimal invasive, meaning do not modify your C code because someone could try to use the lib in C++. Modify the C++ code instead.

Comment: @AlexeyFeldgendler You're right. I thought `#define`ing keywords was disallowed, but it seems that was only a coding standard, not a language standard.

Comment: It is even, in fact, sometimes done for a reason. I've seen e.g. `new` and `delete` defined to complex expressions to help track the origins of every memory allocation.

Comment: The first macro did it. I put it in the C headers, since I have already created a fork of the library for my own needs. Being minimally invasive is good in some cases, but I'd like to make the library itself "C++ proof".

Comment: @ArneMertz: There is value in either approach. If the C library is under your control, then you might want to *improve* it to have a C++ compatible interface, which would imply adding both the empty `restrict` define and the `extern "C"` blocks. The advantage there is that you need to handle support for C++ in a single location. If you don't have control over the library, then the external (i.e. around the `#include`) macro is needed --but note that this will need to be done consistently in all TUs that include the header

Comment: Something else to consider is for each header `<foo.h>` in the library that you would normally include in your C++, add a `<cfoo>` which just does the `extern "C" { #define restrict ...` and include it in your C++ instead.